# Mesh breaking/deformed after sculpting?

Tags: modeling, sculpting

I'm quite new to blender and I've got lots of help from here recently I appreciate a lot! The problem I'm facing now is that the corner part of my couch starts breaking or making a weird extruded shapes along the edge of the object after sculpting. When sculpting, everything looks okay but then whenever I save the file they become like this. I removed doubles and tried to recalculate or flip directions but still don't know what I missed. Or maybe it's something I have to start from the beginning again?

[image]

[image]

This file above is before I smooth the edges on sculpting mode. If I save the file after smoothing then it always changes to the file below with deformed edges.

[image]

This is the file with changed shape

Comment: Try maybe pressing Apply Base in the modifier options. While it's hard to tell what's really wrong there as it might depend on how you smoothened, still it shouldn't be changed itself after saving, maybe it's a bug.

Comment: It sorted it out perfectly! Thanks a lot. I don't know either what went wrong since I tried to sculpt over and over again but happened whenever I saved. But the solution you gave me works great for me and I'm sure it will help out other people with similar problems.